# Custom Iteration over a list item in Python

Tags: python, list, iteration

I have a list in python with following sample contents:

```
['mark', 29, 'american', 'james', 45, 'british', 'arthur', 76, 'australian']
```

as is clear from the pattern the first item in a list is name, second is age and the third is nationality. 
What will be the most efficient way of iterating over it so as to separate the elements inside one for loop.

I am new to python and do not know the best method of doing it.

```
for i in len(0, len(my_list):
    name = 
    age = 
    nationality =
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one method of doing it is:

```
names = mylist[0::3]
ages = mylist[1::3]
nationalities = mylist[2::3]
```

you can then iterate as

```
for name in names:
    print name
etc.
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this handy pattern:

```
from itertools import izip

iters = [iter(my_list)] * 3   # change 3 to number of items in each group
for name, age, nationality in izip(*iters):
     print name, age, nationality
```

Comment: Interesting and works with any iterable as source, not just lists.

Answer (score 3):

Just loop in steps of 3:

```
for i in xrange(len(my_list)/3):
    name, age, nationality = my_list[3*i:3*i+3]
```

Comment: len takes only one arguement, two given. if we change len to range we get an error :TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'

Comment: Arithmetic with indices is not very pythonic. In general that style is error prone.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to implement new kinds of iteration is to write a generator.  They let you encapsulate the iteration style and separate it from the rest of your code:

```
def by_threes(seq):
    it = iter(seq)
    while True:
        yield next(it), next(it), next(it)

for a, b, c in by_threes(range(20)):
    print a,b,c
```

prints:

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
9 10 11
12 13 14
15 16 17
```

If you had need to tuplize a sequence flexibly, you could use this:

```
def by_chunks(seq, n):
    """Yield lists [a,b,..] from `seq`, each list having `n` elements."""
    l = []
    for i, x in enumerate(seq):
        l.append(x)
        if (i % n) == n-1:
            yield l
            l = []
```

Answer (score 3):

Use step indices with [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) (or [`itertools.izip`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip)):

```
>>> l = ['mark', 29, 'american', 'james', 45, 'british', 'arthur', 76, 'australian']
>>> for name, age, nationality in zip(l[::3], l[1::3], l[2::3]):
...     print (name, age, nationality)
... 
('mark', 29, 'american')
('james', 45, 'british')
('arthur', 76, 'australian')
```